# Android SDK Manager won't download packages

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

So I tried to download some packages for the Android SDK. I later decided to delete them but then I found that I would need them, so I'm trying to re-download them, but I can't. Help me figure this out:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\docs-23_r01.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-23_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-22_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 23, revision 2
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-23_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 22, revision 6
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-22_r06.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 3
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\sysimg_armv7a-15_r03.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-21_r01.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 17
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis_x86-19_r17.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 17
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-19_r17.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 4
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-18_r04.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 4
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-17_r04.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 4
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-16_r04.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 3
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\google_apis-15_r03.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\sources-23_r01.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1
URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\sources-22_r01.zip (Access is denied)
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 7'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22, revision 7'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 9'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 9'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 21, revision 9'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 7'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 22, revision 1'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Comment: Give access to your C: drive to write files

Comment: Try this,  Android SDK Manager--> Tools--> Option-->click on Clear cache after Refreshing the List by  Android SDK Manager --> Packages --> Reload. I think it work.

Answer (score 15):

You should run Android SDK Manager in Administrator mode if you're on Windows. Had the problem once, it should fix the rights problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using from proxy (First enable your proxy):

[image]

After above works, in `Android SDK Manager`-->select `Packages` --> `Reload`.

You can download packages with proxy now.

If you can't download, you can use from this link : [androidsdkoffline](http://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-501-api-21-lollipop-direct.html)